Aorist forms in Rigveda
I am going through the Rigveda and the aorist forms are used very commonly as expected. The aorist (लुङ्) by itself denotes an action occurring in the past tense from my understanding, but:
For example, the aorist imperative:
स नः पितेव सूनवेऽग्ने सूपायनो भव (Present imperative)
[Like a father is to his son, may Agni be to us easily accessible]
वायवा याहि दर्शतेमे सोमा अरंकृताः । तेषां पाहि श्रुधी हवम् ।। (Aorist imperatives; here interestingly याहि is present imperative)
[O beautiful Vayu! Come hither! Hear our invocation! Drink from the ritual drink we have prepared for you!]
Similarly the aorist subjunctive:
अग्निना रयिमश्नवत्पोषमेव दिवेदिवे । यशसं वीरवत्तमम् ॥ (अश्नवत् is Present subjunctive)
[Through Agni, may we obtain riches that increase day by day]
अग्निर्होता कविक्रतुः सत्यश्चित्रश्रवस्तमः । देवो देवेभिरा गमत् ॥ (Aorist subjunctive)
[May Agni come hither to our sacrifice accompanied by other Gods]
Clearly the aorist imperative and subjunctive forms can not imply past tense in these suktas. How are they different in nuance or interpretation from the non-aorist imperative and subjunctive here?
Is there anything similar in other Indo-European languages, like Greek?

To the down-voters: I have added a bit about other IE languages. Everyone happy now?

@fdb It is not clear that your edit is in line with OP's intent. If this question were about, say, Italian, it would be closed as a question about "usage" rather than "linguistics".

In many Indo-European languages, including both Sanskrit and Ancient Greek, verbs are marked for both tense (when the action happened) and aspect (how the action relates to that time). This is the difference between the imperfect and aorist in Greek, for example: both are past, but one indicates a duration, the other a point.
However, many verb forms don't actually include tense information, only aspect. In these forms, like the imperative and infinitive, the aorist still indicates a single point in time—but it doesn't have to be in the past.
That's what's happening here. The "present" forms here are actually imperfective, indicating a duration, while the "aorist" forms are perfective (or sometimes aoristic), indicating a point. Agni should be accessible for a long time, but Vayu drinking the drink will just happen and be done. Obtaining riches might take a long time, but coming to the sacrifice will only happen once.

In Sanskrit, as in Greek, the aorist is used for past action only in the indicative mood. In the other moods (subjunctive, optative, imperative etc.) the present refers to continuous action and the aorist to completed action.

That is useful. I've added simple translations of the Sanskrit verses in English. If possible, could you elaborate through examples what the distinction in meanings would be between the present and aorist for them?

@elbord77 In your third example "day by day" implies repeated  or continuous action. In the fourth it is a single sacrifice.
